# can't get the body response of wordline webhook after payment

Tags: webhooks, payment-processing

I set up a payment with Wordline and I added a webhook URL to send the payment details, the problem after redirecting to this url the body of the request is empty
`$returnUrl = $this->generateUrl("app_webhook_ogone",[],UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
$returnUrl = "https://a472-195-135-0-107.ngrok-free.app/webhook/ogone";
try {
$response   =  $ogoneService->createPaymentRequest($order,$hostedTokenizationId,$returnUrl);
} catch (DeclinedPaymentException $e) {
return $this->json("Le paiment a été réfuser",Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
} catch (ApiException $e) {
return $this->json("Une erreur s'est produite veuillez réessayer plus tard",Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}

```
    $actionType = $response->getMerchantAction()->getActionType();
    switch($actionType){
        case null :
            dd($statusCode);
            break;
            case 'REDIRECT':
                return $this->json($redirectUrlFor3DSecure,Response::HTTP_OK); 
                break;
                
            }`
```

this work fine then when i try to get payment details
`#[Route('/webhook/ogone', name :'app_webhook_ogone', methods:['POST','GET'])]
public function getPaymentInformations(Request $request)
{
dd($request->getContent());

```
    return new Response(null,Response::HTTP_OK) ;
}`  the `$request->getContent()` is an empty string
```

i create the paymentRequest with this code
`$returnUrl = $this->generateUrl("app_webhook_ogone",[],UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
$returnUrl = "https://a472-195-135-0-107.ngrok-free.app/webhook/ogone";
try {
$response   =  $ogoneService->createPaymentRequest($order,$hostedTokenizationId,$returnUrl);
} catch (DeclinedPaymentException $e) {
return $this->json("Le paiment a été réfuser",Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
} catch (ApiException $e) {
return $this->json("Une erreur s'est produite veuillez réessayer plus tard",Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}

```
    $actionType = $response->getMerchantAction()->getActionType();
    switch($actionType){
        case null :
            dd($statusCode);
            break;
            case 'REDIRECT':
                return $this->json($redirectUrlFor3DSecure,Response::HTTP_OK); 
                break;
                
            }`
```

` public function createPaymentRequest(Order $order,string $hostedTokenizationId,string $returnUrl)
{

```
    $paymentRequest = new CreatePaymentRequest();
    $paymentRequest->setHostedTokenizationId($hostedTokenizationId);

    $redirectionData = new RedirectionData();
    $redirectionData->setReturnUrl($returnUrl);

    $threeDSecure = new ThreeDSecure();
    $threeDSecure->setRedirectionData($redirectionData);
    
    $cardPaymentMethodSpecificInput = new CardPaymentMethodSpecificInput();
    // $cardPaymentMethodSpecificInput->setPaymentProductId(1);
    $cardPaymentMethodSpecificInput->setSkipAuthentication(false);
    $cardPaymentMethodSpecificInput->setThreeDSecure($threeDSecure);
    // $cardPaymentMethodSpecificInput->setAuthorizationMode('SALE');

    $paymentRequest->setCardPaymentMethodSpecificInput($cardPaymentMethodSpecificInput);

    $references = new OrderReferences();
    $references->setMerchantReference($order->getId());
   
    
    $ogoneOrder = new OgoneOrder();
    $ogoneOrder->setReferences($references);

    $browserData = new BrowserData();
    $browserData->setColorDepth(24);
    $browserData->setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    $browserData->setScreenHeight("1080");
    $browserData->setScreenWidth("1920");

    $customerDevice = new CustomerDevice();
    $customerDevice->setAcceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xmlq=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*q=0.8,application/signed-exchangev=b3");
    $customerDevice->setLocale("fr_FR");
    $customerDevice->setTimezoneOffsetUtcMinutes("-180");
    $customerDevice->setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0 Win64 x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36");
    $customerDevice->setBrowserData($browserData);

    $customer = new Customer();
    $customer->setDevice($customerDevice);
    
    $ogoneOrder->setCustomer($customer);
 
    

    $amountOfMoney = new AmountOfMoney();
    $amountOfMoney->setAmount(($order->getTotalPrice() + $order->getDeliveryCost()) * 100);
    // $amountOfMoney->setAmount(1302);
    $amountOfMoney->setCurrencyCode("EUR");
    
    

    $ogoneOrder->setAmountOfMoney($amountOfMoney);
    

    $paymentRequest->setOrder($ogoneOrder);
    
     # Initialise the client with the apikey, apisecret and URI
     $connection = new DefaultConnection();

     $communicatorConfiguration = new CommunicatorConfiguration(
         $this->apiKey,
         $this->apiSecret,
         $this->apiEndpoint,
         'OnlinePayments'
     );

     $communicator = new Communicator(
         $connection,
         $communicatorConfiguration
     );
     $client = new Client($communicator);
    
   return  $client->merchant($this->pspId)->payments()->createPayment($paymentRequest);

    
}`
```

this work fine then when i try to get payment details
`#[Route('/webhook/ogone', name :'app_webhook_ogone', methods:['POST','GET'])]
public function getPaymentInformations(Request $request)
{
dd($request->getContent());

```
    return new Response(null,Response::HTTP_OK) ;
}`  the `$request->getContent()` is an empty string
```